# Получение температуры процессора C++ WMI Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cpu, wmi

На строке `hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pObject, &returned);` выкидывает ошибку IDispatch error #3587, почему это происходит и как это можно исправить?

Вызов функции: 
`LONG temp;
test(&temp);
qDebug() << (static_cast<double>(temp) / 10 - 273.15);`
Выводит 273.25, всегда.

Вот вся функция для получения температуры процессора:

```
    HRESULT test(LPLONG pTemperature)
{
    if (pTemperature == NULL)
           return E_INVALIDARG;

       *pTemperature = -1;
       HRESULT ci = CoInitialize(NULL); // needs comdef.h
       HRESULT hr = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
       qDebug() << hr;
       if ((SUCCEEDED(hr)) || hr == -2147417831)
       {
           IWbemLocator *pLocator; // needs Wbemidl.h & Wbemuuid.lib
           hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemAdministrativeLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLocator);
           if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
           {
               IWbemServices *pServices;
               BSTR ns = SysAllocString(L"root\\WMI");
               hr = pLocator->ConnectServer(ns, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &pServices);
               pLocator->Release();
               SysFreeString(ns);
               if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
               {
                   BSTR query = SysAllocString(L"SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");
                   BSTR wql = SysAllocString(L"WQL");
                   IEnumWbemClassObject *pEnum;

                   hr = pServices->ExecQuery(wql, query, WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY | WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY, NULL, &pEnum);
                   SysFreeString(wql);
                   SysFreeString(query);
                   pServices->Release();
                   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                   {
                       IWbemClassObject *pObject;
                       ULONG returned;
                       hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pObject, &returned);

                       _com_error err(hr);
                       LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
                       qDebug() << QString::fromStdWString(errMsg);

                       pEnum->Release();
                       if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                       {
                           BSTR temp = 
                           SysAllocString(L"CurrentTemperature");
                           VARIANT v;
                           VariantInit(&v);
                           hr = pObject->Get(temp, 0, &v, NULL, NULL);
                           pObject->Release();
                           SysFreeString(temp);
                           if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                           {
                               *pTemperature = V_I4(&v);
                               qDebug() << *pTemperature;
                           }
                           VariantClear(&v);
                       }
                   }
               }
               if (ci == S_OK)
               {
                   CoUninitialize();
               }
           }
       }
       return hr;
}
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, WMI не обязан (!) на всех ОС, платформах и версиях дров выдавать эту информацию. И очень вероятно, что у вас и не выдает.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Случайно не ту функцию скинул, но суть осталась та же, только класс MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature, а с Win32_TemperatureProbe я пробовал, он возвращал 0, что, насколько я понимаю, и значит, что нет поддержки от драйверов.

Comment: Скорее всего. Температура на современных камнях может быть получена через MSR, но соответствующие инструкции из юзермода недоступны.

Comment: MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature может представлять любое устройство или группу устройств, далеко не обязательно процессор. Если зон несколько, нет способа определить, в какой из них процессор - у зоны нет ничего, кроме номера. А Win32_TemperatureProbe в стандартной реализации возвращает значение из таблицы SMBIOS при загрузке, а не реальное показание датчика. Так что метод, боюсь, бесперспективный.

Answer (score 1):

После обсуждения в теме [Как получить температуру с помощью win32_temperatureprobe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756224/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-win32-temperatureprobe/759691#759691) я заинтересовался данным вопросом, проверил оба компьютера дома и попросил студентов на работе набрать статистику на разных машинах (обязательно: разные материнские платы) вот такой функции (написано на c#, но это не имеет значения):

```
void get_cpu_temp()
{
    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");
        Console.Write(searcher.Get());
        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            double kelvin10 = double.Parse(queryObj["CurrentTemperature"].ToString());
            double celcium = (kelvin10 - 2732) * 0.1;
            Console.Write(celcium.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException err)
    {
        Console.Write("Ошибка: " + err.Message);
    }
}
```

К сожалению, машины у нас закупаются партиями, поэтому проверено всего лишь 19 разных машин. Получить температуру удалось только на 4х из них. Наиболее часто встречающийся код ошибки - 259. На одном компьютере зафиксирован повторяющийся BSOD (!). Так что, на мой взгляд, полагаться на то, что получится работать с `MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature`, не стоит. Разве что проверять при установке, к примеру, и, если ошибки нет - использовать. Однако, в прошлом я уже наблюдал, что прошивка BIOS может повлиять на работоспособность данного инструмента как в плюс, так и в минус, так что проверять стоит при каждом запуске программы.