# Как получить температуру с помощью win32_temperatureprobe

Tags: c#, wmi

Не получается реализовать получение температуры процессора.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
            {
                byte[] vendorSpec = obj["name"] as byte[];
                if (vendorSpec != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Температура = " + vendorSpec[115]);
                }

            }
```

Comment: WMI берет большинство инфы о железе из таблицы SMBIOS, которая обновляется один раз при загрузке системы. Получить данные о температуре в реальном времени, в общем случае через WMI нельзя. (Мне кажется, или WMI самый переоцениваемый из виндовых API?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, @MSDN.WhiteKnight прав, и вы не получите реальные цифры через WMI.
Но есть небольшой шанс, что на некоторых материнских платах всё же можно получить температуру процессора. Чтобы получить данные, производитель должен обеспечить эту возможность, но он в большинстве случаев это не делает. В свое время ради интереса через powershell  проверял такую возможность на разных компьютерах. ЕМНИП, получилось только на 3х из 15, причём на всех трех стояли Intel'овские мат. платы. На остальных 12ти выдавалась ошибка `Get-WMIObject : Не поддерживается` (на моей текущей плате теперь, после обновления BIOS, выводится то же самое). Выдаваемые значения сравнивал с монитором температур, было похоже, они изменялись со временем, но 100%но утверждать, что это температура именно CPU, всё же не берусь.
Но запрашивать надо не `Win32_Processor`, а `MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature`, а с результатом проводить весьма забавные манипуляции, поскольку температура выдается в десятых долях по шкале Кельвина. В c# без IDE пока не очень силён, IDE под рукой нет, поэтому не обессудьте, если где-то синтаксическая ошибка:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");
  foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Double temp = Convert.ToDouble(obj["CurrentTemperature"].ToString()) - 2732;
                    temp = temp  * 0.1;
                    string name = obj["InstanceName"].ToString();
               // ну, и в TList теперь их (temp и name), к примеру
                }
```

Comment: "но 100%но утверждать, что это температура именно CPU, всё же не берусь" - Какое-то одно из значений, возможно, относится к процессору. ACPI Thermal Zone - это абстракция,
 которая представляет датчик температуры и его критические значения,
 при которых система должна бить тревогу (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/acpi-defined-devices#a-href-idthermalathermal-zones). Но свойства, к какому именно устройству она относится, нету, есть только безликий идентификатор типа TZ00, TZ01

Comment: А у меня скрипт не выдал ошибки, мать на AMD'шном чипсете. Температура от термодатчика процессора будто бы слегка отстает по времени

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov сбросьте мне, пожалуйста, на ящик данные по вашей материнской плате. Пожалуй, снова заинтересуюсь данным вопросом. Спасибо!